# The 'romantic approach' of Goro Shimura?

Tags: soft-question, math-history

In the Wikipedia page of [Shimura](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goro_Shimura). There is an interesting sentence without reference (3rd paragraph under the section *Life and career*):

> He also argues for a *'romantic' approach*, something he finds lacking in the younger generation of mathematician.

I'm curious about what did he mean exactly in this context, since, half-seriously, I'm young and would like to grow into a 'romantic' mathematician, a number theorist in particular.

I shall appreciate any comment.

Comment: I hope people will pardon me, but I think you should not take this remark seriously. In part, for example, I think it is in the same vein as the stereotypical "Kids these days don't realize..." riff. It ought not be surprising that the sort of person who may be a very successful mathematician is not reliably the same sort who is able to understand other peoples' impulses and sensibilities. And there is a sadly-too-common pattern of bitterness that one has/had not been more "romantic heroic" than one managed. But mythology and fantasy are not necessarily a good guide for ... life... I think.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I agree that it might be stereotypical----I'm just trying to see if he's given any detailed account on that, since personally I find him a mathematician with interesting ideas:)

Comment: try his autobiography, http://www.springer.com/us/book/9780387797144  or  http://oskicat.berkeley.edu/record=b13656606~S1

Comment: @LCZHao curiously the Japanese version of the same Wikipedia page does not include that reference.I have been trying to look for the context, and that comment of the Wiki page was included by a kind Professor that was user of Math Overflow, so maybe you can ask directly him in the Wikipedia talk feature for a little reference... https://mathoverflow.net/users/6153/charles-matthews  My guess is that probably it comes from one of Goro's general books about mathematics,that again curiously are not in the English page but are in the Japanese wiki (maybe there is not English translation)

Comment: @WillJagy Thanks! I'll look it up when I have time!

Comment: @iadvd Thanks for the information! I'll try it!

Comment: @iadvd I can see there is already a request for the reference at the corresponding talk page, dating back to 2016. I hope the author will answer it in the future...

Comment: @LCZhao good catch! sorry I did not see that... I will try to look in Japanese later. I will be back if I find something.